Extending a holomorphic function to be holomorphic on all of $D$

Let $D$ be a domain, $a \in  D, B\left( {a, R}\right)  \subset  D, f$ is holomorphic in $B\left( {a, R}\right)  \smallsetminus  \{ a\}$. Prove that there exists a  holomorphic function $F$ defined on $D \smallsetminus  \{ a\}$ such that $\mathop{\lim }\limits_{{z \rightarrow  a}}\left\lbrack  {F\left( z\right)  - f\left( z\right) }\right\rbrack   = 0$, hence $F - f \in  H\left( {B\left( {a, R}\right) }\right)$.

If we just extend $f$ in a $C^\infty$ sense, it is OK. since we may use a cut-off function $\phi$ such that $\phi\in C^\infty$, $\phi|_{B(0,R/2)}=1, \phi|_{B(0,R)}=0$. $\phi f$ is OK! But how to extend $f$ holomorphically?

Take the Laurent expansion of $f$ at $a$ and note that the negative powers part $F$ converges on the punctured plane so defines a holomorphic function on the bigger domain $D$ except at $a$ and clearly $F-f$ is holomorphic on the full disc centered at $a$ and of radius $R$
